# Why is there a 0.5 in this loss?

Tags: pytorch, cosine-distance, loss

I'm reading this paper and I don't understand why the squared L2-norm is also multiplied by 0.5 in the loss.
They want a loss that measures the distance between two feature maps. Why don't they use just the squared l2 norm?

paper link:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.04257v3.pdf
(see page 5)

Comment: i think i got it. They are using the cosine distance and you can express the cosine distance as 0.5*euclidean_distance

Comment: First, the cosine distance is not 0.5 * euclidean distance, [check it out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). About the question, isn't the 1/2 to cancel out the 2 when taking the derivative?

Comment: @noe you are right, it's not 0.5*euclidean distance, but it can be expressed using euclidean distance (if A and B are l2 normalized) as that: cos_dist(A,B) = eucl_dist(A-B) * 0.5